# CodeIgniter can't read other files in view folder

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to use an `<a>` tag to load a file in my view folder but it just won't work.

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url("residents/information"); ?>">Records</a>
```

I already put `$this->load->helper('url');` in the `function __construct()` in my default controller(`$route['default_controller'] = "residents";`)
and set `$autoload['helper'] = array('url');` in my autoload.php

I can load all of my view using `$this->load->view();` but cant load it using `site_url()`
The only files that I can load using `site_url()` are the files in the root directory of codeigniter.

Can anybody tell me what should I do in order to make `site_url()` load my view files? Thanks

Comment: do you want to load files from views folder?

Comment: Whats is it that you're trying to accomplish that cant be done with $this->load->view(); ?

Comment: Yes sir. I want to load it using <a> tag. So that I can just load the files by clicking the links in my header

Comment: every thing can be done my $this->load->view();
But I want to load it using site_url

Answer (score 0):

your question is not clear but its a guess

use base_url() instead of site_url().Hope it will work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion sir but I still can't make it work. I used base_url() insted of site_url() but error 404 still occurs.

Comment: actually your question is confusing.ok let me know one thing when you click on the <a> tag then what it says?

Comment: I'm apologize for the confusing question. It says "The page you requested was not found."

Comment: Then i think its a problem of .htaccess. have you omitted index.php from the config file?

Comment: Yes I omitted index.php. This is also the content of my .htaccess
RewriteEngine on   
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f   
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d   
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]

Comment: Your .htaccess content is ok except the last line. I think it should be RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] not RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L].please do the changes and let me know as i have used this one.

Comment: Still have the same result sir. It works in just one file though. my main view which is index.php

Comment: can you show me the information function that you wrote?

Comment: I inputted $this->template->set_partial('header', 'partials/header', $userInfo); and $this->template->build('residents/index'); in the function index in my default controller .

Comment: I just echoed some text in the information.php in the view to see if its working

Comment: this $this->template->set_layout('default'); is also in my default controller.